# Failed dependencies

Tags: centos, libraries, dependencies

I am searching for the following :

1. libpython2.5.so.1.0
2. libtinfo.so.5
3. python(abi) = 2.5

I searched , but I am not able to find these. I am running Centos 5.6 with linux kernel 2.6.18-238.el5.

```
$ rpm -q --provides python | grep -Fw 'python(abi)'
python(abi) = 2.4
```

As far as I searched, libtinfo.so.5 is a part of ncurses library now. But It is searching for that specific dependecy library.

My current python version is 2.4.3. If someone has any idea about installing these dependencies please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to install a binary RPM that was built for a different version of Linux.

It is quite possible that even if you satisfy the dependencies that RPM is complaining about that the resulting program still will not install or work correctly. RPM-based Linuxes are not mutually compatible in all respects. Python is a particular area of incompatibility because it is so widely used in a Red Hat-derived system like CentOS. Because of this, trying to upgrade or install a parallel version of Python to satisfy the dependencies is likely to cause a lot of other problems and still may not solve all of your RPM compatibility problems.

Instead, it will probably work out much better in the end for you to build the RPM from source, if at all possible. Ideally, from [an SRPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRPM). It would only be impossible if the package provider does not provide any form of source code or the package absolutely requires Python 2.5 and will not run on Python 2.4.

If you can get an SRPM, the rebuild process may be as simple as:

```
# rpmbuild --rebuild name-of-package.version.src.rpm
```

The advantage of that is that the resulting binary RPM is built against the libraries on your system, so that if it builds, it is almost guaranteed to work.

Comment: Yeah I guessed the mismatch. But I dont exactly know the right kernel. I am trying Fedora 8 right now. I installed it from the live cd and found it has the required python(abi) = 2.5. But the eth0 interface is not detected. My machine has Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet controller. Looks like fedora 8 doesnt have the required driver. I am still confused how to solve this.

Comment: If changing to an entirely different flavor of Linux just to get one RPM to work is a reasonable solution in your case, you can probably solve all your problems by using some sort of Virtual Machine technology. (VMware, VirtualBox, Xen, KVM...) That will let you continue to use CentOS, which works with your hardware, yet use the flavor of Linux that the RPM was built on. If that solution won't work, then I repeat my advice: rebuild the RPM from source on CentOS.

Comment: Thanks guess that is the best solution "compiling from source". I was able to install driver modules, install the rpm (works fine and creates a new kernel) . When I boot using that newly created kernel , I get :

Comment: Volume group "VOLGROUP00" not found.
mount: couldnt find filesystem '/dev/root'
setuproot: moving /dev failed: no such file or directory
setuproot:error mounting /proc: no such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /sys: no such file or directory
switchroot: mount failed: no such file or directory.

Answer (score 2):

The third quickly shows the big problem - you need Python 2.5 ([definition of ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)).

This is one of the problems with RHEL/CentOS - you have "old" stuff when compared to "Internet speed."

Running parallel versions of python can be a pain. One quick search revealed [some 2.5 and 2.6 RPMs](http://www.geekymedia.com/uncategorized/rhel5-centos5-rpms-for-python-2-5-and-2-6/) that may help. Most likely it will make the executable name be `python25` or `python2.5` .